# Perl loop to wait for adb devices array

Tags: perl

I hope someone will be able to help with why my while loop won't exit when I attach two Android devices.

With the help of SO research I have managed to cobble together the code below, however I have added a while loop to wait for a response to the Android 'adb devices' command.  I am looking to sit in this while loop waiting for two Android devices to be connected via USB to my PC, or when the two connected devices are switched on.  My code compiles ok, and is able to work through the while loop when the devices are already switched on and connected, but when I start the script with the USB cables to the android devices disconnected, and then a few seconds later plug the USB connections in to my PC, the script still sits in the loop. I am running this script on the latest Strawberry Perl on Windows 7.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code...

```
    use strict;
    use warnings qw(all);

    use IPC::Run3;
    use Carp qw(croak confess cluck);
    use Data::Dumper;

    my @devices = get_devices();
    my $devicesattached = "";

    while (!@devices){
            get_devices();
            print ".";
            sleep (1);
            last if @devices;
    }

    print "\n\tDevice 1 is $devices[0]";
    print "\n\tDevice 2 is $devices[1]\n";

    sub get_devices {
        my $adb_out;
        run3 ["adb", "devices"], undef, \$adb_out, undef;
        $? and cluck "Warning: non-zero exit status from adb ($?)";

        my @res = $adb_out =~ m/^([[:xdigit:]]+) \s+ device$/xmg;
        return wantarray ? @res : \@res;
    }
```

Many thanks,
MikG

Comment: You never change `@devices` once you enter the loop.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Your comment is correct, and should be written as an answer.

Comment: @Borodin Working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never change `@devices` once you enter the loop. The simplest fix is to change

```
while (!@devices) {
    get_devices();
```

to

```
while (!@devices) {
    @devices = get_devices();
```

However, you can simplify your code further:

```
my @devices;
until (@devices = get_devices()) {
    print ".";
    sleep 1;
}
```

Note that Perl has a [built-in debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) that can help you in situations like this. Run it like:

```
perl -d /path/to/my/script
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will give this a go tomorrow and get back to you.  Though having seen your examples it seems obvious now...still learning!

Comment: Thanks ThisSuitIsBlackNot, it works! This is exactly what I was looking for.